# Advanced Custom Fields scope issues with Roots Sage 9

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, acfpro, roots-sage

I’m using Roots Sage 9 inside WordPress and utilising the `FrontPage.php` controller which already has `protected $acf = true;` defined in it which is working okay, it outputs what I expect it to for the most part.

In my ACF configuration for the front page I have a relationship field (portfolio_items) which pulls through posts from a custom post type called `portfolio` and inside here are a number of additional ACF fields.

Now, the issue I’m having is what I can only imagine is something like ACF’s scope. For things defined inside the front page ACF fields the whole `protected $acf` works fine, but inside my foreach I’m trying to access ACF fields defined inside the custom post type and I just can’t get them to out put the info. For example, I have a text field defined called “archive title” and I’d usually output it with `the_field('archive_title')` but as I’m trying to use controllers I’d tried to use it as `$archive_title` with no luck, I just get ***“Notice: Undefined Variable: archive_title”***

Here’s the full code I’m using at the minute:

```
    <?php global $post ?>
    @foreach($portfolio_items as $post)
        @php(setup_postdata($post))
        @php($thumbnail = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), "xlarge" ))
        @php($thumbnail_image = $thumbnail[0])
        <a href="{{ the_permalink() }}" class="col-md-3 direction-reveal__card">
            <img src="{{ $thumbnail_image }}" alt="Image" class="direction-reveal__img">
            <div class="direction-reveal__overlay direction-reveal__anim--enter">
                <h3 class="direction-reveal__title mt-auto">{{ $archive_title }}</h3>
            </div>
        </a>                
    @endforeach
    <?php wp_reset_postdata();  ?>
```

I can’t think of a way to fully access the other fields correctly. Has anyone come across this at all?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding well I can suggest this, you should rename your local $post variable from your foreach to something else like $current_post and if you want to call any field associated with an external post outside of your loop you can pass a post id to the get_field() function like: get_field('external_post_field', $post_id);

Hope this can help you.